# Why can't python script find file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use a python script, but when it cannot find the webm I want to compress with it. Yes, I am sure that the webm is called "Typical", has the file extension .webm and is on my Desktop.

Here is the link to the script: https://github.com/HelpSeeker/Restricted-WebM

[image: Image of console where i want to execute restrict.py]

Comment: Can you launch *ffprobe* manually?

Comment: @CristiFati I have it laying on my Desktop.

Comment: That's not quite the answer to the question.  What happens if you run `ffprobe` from the command line?  Does it work, is the executable in your path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FFmpeg and FFprobe need to be part of your PATH for this script to work. The problem is that it changes into the output folder (in your case Desktop\webm_done) for the conversion, so it doesn't have access to the local executables anymore.

> For now add those two executables to your PATH and it should work. Putting FFmpeg/FFprobe next to the script should be a viable option though, so I'll soon update the script to work with absolute output paths instead of changing directories.

HelpSeeker